# Correct way to nest components so that Lightning Events fire

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

So, I set about implementing a Picklist component for the [SDLS Picklist](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/picklist/) and am having a problem with propagation and firing of events.

For this, I created the top level picklist component (detail excluded for brevity) with an event handler to handle clicks on the list options:

```
<!-- picklist.cmp -->
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="label" type="String" default=""/>

    <!-- when an option is clicked... -->
    <aura:handler name="onSelectPicklistOption" event="c:onSelectPicklistOptionEvent" action="{!c.handleSelectOption}"/> 

    <div aura:id="picklist" class="slds-picklist slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger--click">
        <!-- detail excluded -->
        {!v.body}
    </div>    
</aura:component>
```

Note, I'm using an event so that I can call the parent method from the child component.

Then, the controller with handler:

```
({
    // wanting to fire onSelectPicklistOptionEvent
    handleSelectOption: function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('handleSelectOption')
    }
})
```

Then, I created a picklistOption (child to picklist) component (again, unimportant detail excluded), registering the event and calling from the `toggle` function:

```
<!-- picklistOption.cmp -->
<aura:component >
    <!-- Picklist option selected -->
    <aura:registerEvent name="onSelectPicklistOption" type="c:onSelectPicklistOptionEvent"/>

    <li role="presentation">
        <span onclick="{!c.toggle}">
        </span>
    </li>
</aura:component>
```

the associated controller to call the parent picklist event...

```
({
    toggle : function(component, event, helper) {
        // select this one and de-select the others
        var selectOptionEvent = component.getEvent("onSelectPicklistOption");
        selectOptionEvent.setParams({
            "option": component
        });
        selectOptionEvent.fire();

        // also tried $A.get('e.c:onSelectPicklistOptionEvent')
    }
})
```

And finally, I create my picklist in my `layout` component, setting the body of the picklist as `picklistOption`'s:

```
<!-- layout.cmp -->
<aura:component>
    <c:picklist label="Pick an option">
        <c:picklistOption text="test0" label="Test0"/>
        <c:picklistOption text="test1" label="Test1"/>
    </c:picklist>
</aura:component>
```

Sadly, the picklist `handleSelectOption` does not get called. This seems to be because the event handler is declared in the `picklist` component but the `picklistOption`'s are basically declared in the `layout` component. I can fix this by putting my `aura:handler` in the `layout` component but that doesn't seem right to me since `picklist` is no longer encapsulated.

Am I missing the point on how to nest child components within its parent and thus causing this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some digging, I found that you need to declare your handler with the `includeFacets="true"` attribute, found in [this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component_bubbling.htm).

So, the picklist component becomes:

```
<!-- picklistOption.cmp -->
<aura:component >
    <!-- Picklist option selected -->
    <aura:registerEvent name="onSelectPicklistOption" type="c:onSelectPicklistOptionEvent" 
        includeFacets="true"/>

    <li role="presentation">
        <span onclick="{!c.toggle}">
        </span>
    </li>
</aura:component>
```

See this excerpt from the documentation:

> ### Propagation to All Container Components
>
> The default behavior doesn’t
>   allow an event to be handled by every parent in the containment
>   hierarchy. Some components contain other components but aren’t the
>   owner of those components. These components are known as container
>   components. In the example, c:container is a container component
>   because it’s not the owner for c:eventSource. By default, c:container
>   can’t handle events fired by c:eventSource.
>
> A container component has a facet attribute whose type is
>   Aura.Component[], such as the default body attribute. The container
>   component includes those components in its definition using an
>   expression, such as {!v.body}. The container component isn’t the owner
>   of the components rendered with that expression.
>
> To allow a container component to handle the event, add
>   includeFacets="true" to the  tag of the container
>   component. For example, adding includeFacets="true" to the handler in
>   the container component, c:container, enables it to handle the
>   component event bubbled from c:eventSource.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it really helped me out tonight. However, the `includeFacets` attribute should be on `aura:handler`, not `aura:registerEvent`.